# SSIS package frozen during a Data Flow cleanup only on a specific server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package which executes on several environments. On a specific server, the package freezes randomly during the cleanup of a dataflow. It happens randomly, and not every time.

I tried my best to reproduce this problem, but I never succeded.

This data flow is reading from a flat text file, executes several lookups and a custom script transform, then insert the data in a Sql Server db, using Ole Db.

When it freezes, the log looks like :

```
...       
Progress: 2011-04-04 12:39:59.57
Source: Data Flow Task
Cleanup: 81% complete
End Progress
```

then nothing for hours... The percent complete is not necessarely the same when it freezes.

I tried to understand what is happening during the cleanup phase in order to search on the package which entity is causing the freeze, but I didn't find anything relevant.

I asserted that :

- If the problem was related to a table
  lock, it would raise a timeout error
- It works on the designer ( 32 bits
  runtime ) and on the 64 bits runtime
  on a dev server, so the problem may
  not be related to the runtime
- the problem seems to be related to the server or the db instance, but all environment are identical : Sql Server 2008 and Windows Server 2003 R2 x64, configuration are identicals.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "the problem seems to be related to the server or the db instance" - information about which you neglect to include!

Comment: Sql Server 2008 and Windows Server 2003 R2 x64. All systems are identical on each environment. Systems and servers configurations are identicals.

Comment: "All systems are identical on each environment" - if I had a dollar for every time I've heard that! (and indeed, said that!)

Comment: You would be rich ! I should say : the servers are in the same version and have the same updates applied.